# how to fillna the nan value in age feature for the titanic data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-engineering

I wan to fill the nan value in age feature . In the titatic train data pclass and embarked feature are independent feature .Based on these feature I want to fill the nan value of the age feature.
Pclass - (0,1,2) unique value, Embarked - ('S','Q','C') and target feature
Survived - (0,1)

for the pclass, age and target feature(survived):

sns.catplot(x='Pclass', y='Age',hue='Survived', data=train)

for the Embarked, age and target feature(survived):

sns.catplot(x='Embarked', y='Age',hue='Survived', data=train)

But I don't know which one is better .Please tell me which one is better to fill the nan value of the age feature

And Is is right to drop the cabin feature from the training set which has 204 non-null value out of 891 .Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

When I did this titanic experiment I used a Linear Regression model from the scikitlearn library to predict the missing age.

For the cabin, I converted all the missing data to cabin 'M' so I could still use that column of data as input to my model. Which in the end improved my score.

You could also try just putting the average or median age of each 'Pclass' and use that to fill the ages. I believe that worked ok as well.

Comment: It is not a regression algo it is classification algo becoz target feature( survived ) contain 0 and 1 category.

Comment: It is regression if you are trying to predict the age. I agree that the overall algorithm is classification for predicting if survived or not if that's what you mean.

Comment: train['Age']=train['Age'].fillna(train['Age'].median()) or i can fill nan value bassed on pclass